# Getting build errror - Module ri.spark-module-manager.main.spark-module.e2250371-eb6f-4b05-9055-9fc7371b82d4 died while running job. Exit reason: OOM

Tags: environment, oom

I have configured my environment as "profile-high-memory" but am still getting this error message when executing a build in code workbook - Module ri.spark-module-manager.main.spark-module.61b3d476-a5a8-4913-9a50-382f1450705a died while running job. Exit reason: OOM.

I have tried restarting the spark environment.